# Allow to translate "Discussion on answer by" for autogenerated chat room name

Tags: feature-request, chat, localization, russian-stackoverflow

I know that pure chat strings are not allowed to translate for localized sites, but ...

> [image: Discussion on answer by]

... could you please make "Discussion on answer by" string that is visible through the site interface translatable?

Other related strings:

- [Discussion between {userName1} and {userName2}](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94426/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-stranger-in-the-q)
- [Discussion on question by ...](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94896/discussion-on-question-by-deol-entity-framework----)

Comment: I gave this name, it isn't autogeneration. But the offer is generally good.

Comment: @nomnoms12 which name did you give? :)

Comment: I manually created this room and gave her that name. Such a name to make it look like other rooms.

Comment: @nomnoms12 hmm... This is probably a reason why the name of the chat leaked to the site.

Comment: I will take this into account and will create the rooms in Russian in the future :)